# \usepackage{fancyhdr} remove bookmarks

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr, bookmarks, fncychap

I try to make a thesis in pdf and i like to put two things in:

1. Change the style of chapters (Lenny);
2. Put the chapter in a header top on the page;

When i use `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` to do that the bookmarks disappear !

I put here my template so you can see better where I am wrong:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
 \usepackage[dvips,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    pagecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
 }
\usepackage{amsmath,amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{oss}{Osservazione}

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\frenchspacing 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{alltt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{./imgs/}}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[bf]{caption2}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{30pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-30pt}

\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
% \usepackage[]{hyperref}
```

Thanks a lot for Your help !!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded as last package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before

Comment: @ marco daniel answer my first question !!!! I forgot to put this at the end of the page !!!

Comment: Now i like to put the header in all of the pages !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two questions can be solved as follows:

1. Load the package `hyperref` as last package: [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)
2. You are loading the package `fancyhdr` so you can use the package to modify your headers. In your case the following should work:

   ```
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   ```

---

Here I made a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) without unnecessary information:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}%filling text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=false,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    pagecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black,
 }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: The command `\usepackage{blindtext}%filling text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}`

dosen't change the output of my .pdf there aren't headers on the pages ! :(

Comment: @PanichiPattumerosPapaCastoro: Which pages do you mean?

Comment: I finally SOLVE the problem. I must put INTO the 

`\begins{document} ... \end{document}` up the chapter i recall (`\input{chapterN}`) the style !!!! Before i put the `pagestyle{fancy}` out of the document !! Thanks a lot !